# How can WeakHashMap leak memory in Java?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I am running a big Minecraft(Spigot) server with a proprietary, heavily obfuscated AntiCheat plugin as well as our custom set of battle tested plugins. Server is creating and unloading new worlds many times, thus after unload, leaving `CraftPlayer` and `CraftWorld` objects for GC.

We are running on Java 13 (same happens Java 12) with G1GC and so-called "aikar gc flags"

```
java -XX:+UseLargePagesInMetaspace -XX:+UseG1GC 
     -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=100 
     -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90 -XX:G1NewSizePercent=50 
     -XX:G1MaxNewSizePercent=80 -XX:G1MixedGCLiveThresholdPercent=35 
     -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -jar Spigot.jar
```

AntiCheat keeps weak reference to `CraftPlayer`s, and yet they leak, and with the leak big enough the server's CPU is spinning very heavily to ultimately die with `OutOfMemoryError`. Manually running `System.gc()` is not cleaning these up as well.

When AntiCheat is disabled, the leak is gone.

The ONLY gc-root reference in the heapdump to all of the leaked `CraftWorlds` and `CraftPlayer` is the entry in `WeakHashMap`, key being `CraftPlayer`. (`CraftPlayer` and `CraftWorld` cross reference each other before being normally GCd).

There's a way you can make a leak with a `WeakHashMap`: the stale "expired" entries won't be deleted if you aren't actively using get()/set() which triggers `expungeStaleEntries()`. Maybe that would be the cause if AntiCheat was using something like `Map<String, WeakHashMap<...>>`, but that's not the case, it is using one major `WeakHashMap`.

And there's a catch: in this kind of leak, you could see that `WeakHashMap`'s queue would be non-empty! And yet it's empty, as I checked! I also noticed the `WeakHashMap` is wrapped by `synchronizedMap`, but doesn't seem to me like that could be the problem.

Is this really a GC bug caused by one of the flags?

This pattern repeats every time and in every heapdump:

[image: heapdump]

Comment: "Manually running System.gc() is not cleaning these up as well", of course, because command line has `-XX:+DisableExplicitGC`, so explicit GC request has no effect.

Comment: My apologies on production I actually skipped that particular flag, so it's doing the forced GC. I just copy pasted the whole aikar flags.

Comment: `-XX:+UseLargePagesInMetaspace -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=100 -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90 -XX:G1NewSizePercent=50 -XX:G1MaxNewSizePercent=80 -XX:G1MixedGCLiveThresholdPercent=35 -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled`

These are prod GC-related flags.

Comment: Edit the question for everyone to see, please, do not post important amendments in the comments.

Comment: Alright, it's done.

Comment: Additional experiments would tell more: running with other GCs (Serial, Parallel, CMS) to see if the issue is G1-specific. Largely, the weak reference processing in every GC is optional, and may not happen in the time when you want it. It is odd that several Full GCs (triggered by System.gc()) do not clean this up. Note that you need a few cycles to fully flush the non-trivial weak references: first for GC to enqueue them, then for Java-side `ReferenceQueue` to be drained, then another GC to reclaim the rest.

Comment: It's non trivial to get a live server with large leak, as we run several hundread JVM instances, and this might need a really busy day to "fill up" the leak, or maybe even 2-3 days.
Especially I think it needs some anticheat logs to fill up as normal players play.
I planned to check with Shendonnah first so I will deploy that later today everywhere.

Comment: But checking with the best live "suspect" I currently have, running System.gc() 10 times did not seem to make a difference.

Comment: Just guessing: The `WeakHashMap` has weak references to keys, but strong references to values, which in turn may strongly reference the keys. If this is the case, you wouldn't be the first one to encounter the problem.

Comment: interesting. do you think that would be enough to completely confuse both YourKit and VisualVM not to show such reference?

Comment: I had a look at the obfuscated code.
While `Player` comes into `cs` constructor, it's then used by a function that gets a backend class based on client version, and discarded...
If it's really the problem you mentioned if would be much much harder to find...